# Firebase Pagination Trying with Angular 4

Tags: angular, firebase, pagination

not able to fix the problem each time I click nextentries button multiple observables getting returned and next pagination count starts with including the last entry. If you could please help me out this is the code.

```
nextentries(){
   this.posts$ = this.posts$.switchMap(posts => {
    const startAt = posts[posts.length-1].$key;
    console.log(startAt);
    return this.articleService.loadNextPage(startAt, this.postsLimit);
  });
}
```

these are the methods from service which I am calling

```
getAllArticles(query: FirebaseListFactoryOpts = {}): Observable<Article[]> {
      return this.db.list('/articles', query)
      .map(Article.fromJsonList).do(console.log);
       //.publishReplay().refCount()         
    }

loadNextPage(startAt: string, limit ){
    return this.getAllArticles({query: {
        orderByKey:true,
        limitToFirst: 2,
        startAt :startAt 
    }});
    //flatMap( posts => Observable.combineLatest(posts) )
}
```